# Getting the current date (and time) in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I was wondering what is the best way to get the current date in a django application.

Currently I query the python datetime module - but since I need the date all over the place I thought maybe Django already has a buildin function for that.

e.g. I want to filter objects created in the current year so I would do the following:

```
YEAR = datetime.date.now().year
currentData = Data.objects.filter(date__year=YEAR)
```

Should I define the `YEAR` variable in `settings.py` or create a function now() or is there a buildin Function for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In templates, there is already a built-in function [`now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#now):

> Displays the current date and/or time, using a format according to the
>   given string. Such string can contain format specifiers characters as
>   described in the date filter section.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> It is {% now "jS F Y H:i" %}
> ```

In django **1.8**, you can use it with `as`:

```
{% now "Y" as current_year %}
{% blocktrans %}Copyright {{ current_year }}{% endblocktrans %}
```

---

In python code, there is no django builtin for date, just use the python `datetime.date.now()` to make your own customized function.

Comment: Yes for the templates there is, but Iam searching for an equivalent in `views.py`

Comment: in `views.py` you have `datetime.date.now().year`, it does her job well

Comment: It returns the current year and it works well, I just wondered instead of using datetime using a django "buildin" function or writing an own function - so I can use it like a function

Comment: There is no django builtin function for date to use in python code, I think you should do your own function based on `datetime.date.now().year`. I updated my answer

Comment: Just to add more info to an already great answer: If you ever need the current date/time in a template as a variable (`date` or `datetime` instead of `str` as shown in this answer) you can find a few options in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336898/9225671) I wrote some time ago.

Comment: @Ralf - Great answer. Takes care of many situations. And answers Max's answer in **a proper and correct manner**.

Answer (score 3):

I think the fastest and cleanest way is to use the [localdate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localdate) function:

```py
from django.utils.timezone import localdate
today = localdate()
```

Or, there is also [localtime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime), which is the current datetime in the project's timezone:

```py
from django.utils.timezone import localtime
today = localtime().date()
```

However, remember that `now().date()` may be **different** from current date, since it uses UTC:

> Note that now() will always return times in UTC regardless of the value of TIME_ZONE; you can use localtime() to get the time in the current time zone.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can get the the current date in Python **views.py** file in any format you want.

In views.py

```
import datetime

def your(request)
    now=datetime.datetime.now()
    print("Date: "+ now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) #this will print **2018-02-01** that is todays date
```