# Django template - Is there a built-in way to get current date as type 'date' instead of type 'str'?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I know I can get the current date as a `str` in a Django template (using the [template tag `now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#now)), like this:

```
{% now "Y-m-d" as today_str %}
<p>{{ today_str }}</p>
```

But I cannot use that for comparissons:

```
{% now "Y-m-d" as today_str %}

{% for elem in object_list %}
    {% if elem.date < today_str %}        {# WRONG: this compares 'date' and 'str' #}
        <p>{{ elem.pk }} before today</p>
        {# do some other rendering #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

Possible solutions:

1. I know I can pass a context variable to the template, but it requires code in my view:

   ```
   # in my class-based-view in 'views.py'
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       ctx['today'] = timezone.now()
       return ctx
   ```
2. Or I can create a custom template tag, but that is even more additional code.

As you can see I have workarounds for my problem, but I would like to know if there is a buit-in way to get the current `date` (or `datetime`) in the template?

Comment: You can convert a string to datetime object using `datetime.strptime()`. For more details read documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: why not add model property like `return object.date < datetime.now()` or use django timezone?

Comment: @VenkataGogu but I cannot pass arguments to the method `.strptime()` inside a Django template; all methods/functions are called without arguments.

Comment: Similar to a custom template tag, a context processor is another option.

Comment: I would just do those calculations in the view and keep the template as dumb as possible.  At least than you have access to the full datetime library.

Comment: @BearBrown I would like to make many comparissons inside a single template (think of a list of objects); I thought it would be better to not call `timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).date()` for every instance.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes you are right, that is another option I have.

Comment: @Alasdair yes, that is also another option.

Comment: @Ralf by using `cahced_prperty` you can save processor time i think so

Comment: @BearBrown I don't think so; the method marked with `cached_property` still gets called once for every model instance.

Comment: I edited my question; added a loop in the template code

Comment: You can just write a function that takes a `request` object and return something roughly like `{dateobjectnow'': datetime.datatime.now()}` and put it inside the context processors in `projects.settings.TEMPLATES['OPTIONS']['context_processors']`, now every view you have has this template variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, all my searching didn't yield a short solution. The answer to the question seems to be: no, there is no buit-in way to get the current date (or datetime) as a variable in the template.

In case others are searching for this topic, I'll try to give a summary of the possible workarounds that I can up with and that were suggested by other users.

---

1. I could pass a context variable to the template from my view. In class-based views that could look like this (it is even an example in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)):

   ```
    # file 'my_app/views.py'
    from django.utils import timezone as tz
    from django.views.generic import ListView

    class MyView(ListView)
        ...

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

            now = tz.now()
            ctx['now'] = now
            ctx['today'] = tz.localtime(now).date()

            return ctx
   ```
2. I could create a custom [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#context-processors) that loads that variable to every template. In class-based views that could look like this:

   ```
    # file 'context_processors.py'
    from django.utils import timezone as tz

    def now_and_today(request):
        now = tz.now()
        return {
            'now': now,
            'today': tz.localtime(now).date(),
        }

    # file 'settings.py'
    ...
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            ...
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    ...
                    'context_processors.now_and_today',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
    ...
   ```
3. I could create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag), like this:

   ```
    # file 'my_app/custom_template_tags/custom_time_tags.py'
    from django.utils import timezone as tz
    from django import template
    register = template.Library()

    @register.simple_tag
    def get_now(request):
        return tz.now()

    @register.simple_tag
    def get_today(request):
        return tz.localtime(tz.now()).date()
   ```

   To be used like this:

   ```
    {% load 'custom_time_tags' %}

    {% get_today as today %}
    {% for per in person_list %}
        {% if per.brith_date > today %}
            <p>{{ per.name }} is from the future!!<p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
   ```
4. I could also add a property (or even a [`cached_property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property)) to the model:

   ```
    # file 'models.py'
    from django.db import models
    from django.utils import timezone as tz
    from django.utils.functional import cached_property

    class Person(models.Model):
        ...

        @cached_property
        def is_from_future(self):
            # careful: for long-lived instances do not use 'cached_property' as
            # the time of 'now' might not be right later
            if self.birth_date > tz.localtime(tz.now()).date():
                return True

            return False
   ```
5. And last but not least, I could just do the processing in the view and add a property to the elements:

   ```
    # file 'my_app/views.py'
    from django.utils import timezone as tz

    def person_list(request):
        today = tz.localtime(tz.now()).date()

        person_list = []
        for p in Person.objects.all():
            p.is_from_future = self.birth_date > today
            person_list.append(p)

        return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'person_list': person_list})
   ```

Answer (score 0):

From the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#now):

> You can also use the syntax `{% now "Y" as current_year %}` to store the output (as a string) inside a variable. This is useful if you want to use `{% now %}` inside a template tag like [`blocktranslate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#std-templatetag-blocktranslate) for example:
>
> ```
> {% now "Y" as current_year %}
> {% blocktranslate %}Copyright {{ current_year }}{% endblocktranslate %}
> ```